# anesrake - Error in x + weights : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I'm trying to compute sample weights through the `anesrake` package and am consistently getting the above error, despite multiple attempts to troubleshoot. I am weighting on two vars - party identification and political ideology - and don't get the error until I try to execute the anesrake command. I have tried factorizing the target variables, coding them as numeric, and ensuring that there are no NAs, with no luck. I was unable to attach the data file, but the format of the data I'm trying to weight is below, code below that.

| partyid7_ | ideology |
| --- | --- |
| Democrat | Liberal |
| Republican | Conservative |
| Independent | Moderate |

```r
#recoding/labeling target variables
df <- df %>% mutate(pid = case_when(partyid7_ %in% c(1,2) ~ "Democrat",
                                    partyid7_ %in% c(3,4,5) ~ "Independent",
                                    partyid7_ %in% c(6,7) ~ "Republican"),
                    ideol = case_when(ideology %in% c(1,2) ~ "Liberal",
                                      ideology == 3 ~ "Moderate",
                                      ideology %in% c(4,5) ~  
                                                "Conservative"))


# set target variable parameters  
ideol <- c("Liberal", "Moderate", "Conservative") 
ideo_prop <- c(0.25, 0.37, 0.36) #population proportions

pid <- c("Democrat", "Independent", "Republican") 
pid_prop <- c(0.28, 0.41, 0.28) #population parameters

population <- dplyr::data_frame(ideol, pid, ideo_prop, pid_prop) 
    # combining population parameters for target variables into one df

pop <- population %>% mutate(ideol = as.factor(ideol),
                             pid = as.factor(pid))

# create target list of variables to be weighted 
target <- with(pop, list(
  ideol = weights::wpct(ideol, ideo_prop),
  pid = weights::wpct(pid, pid_prop)
))

df$caseid <- 1:length(df$pid)

## creating anesrake object w/vector of weights per respondent
dfrake <- anesrake(target,                     
                   df,                          
                   caseid = df$caseid,               
                   cap = 3,                     
                   choosemethod = "total",     
                   type = "pctlim",            
                   pctlim = 0.05                
)
```